# NuGet Agent gets 503 error for TeamCity feed when on VM

Tags: teamcity, nuget

This is an odd problem;

- I have TeamCity on Ubuntu 12.04 Virtual Machine; Network is Bridged.
- I have an Agent on my Windows 7 Machine running as my domain account.
- I have an Agent on a Windows 8.1 Virtual Machine, running under a
  domain account.
- Its all running on domain with a proxy (automatically picks up domain user).

When I run a build via my windows 7 agent, it all works fine.

When I run a build via the Windows 8.1 Virtual Machine. Nuget Complains it isn't able to access the TeamCity feed. Now the odd thing is I know the domain login and proxy is okay because NuGet is able to access the main online nuget feed!

Apart from the Windows version, there is effectively no difference between the agents; just the VM agent can't access the TeamCity Feed (running as separate VM).

If I remote into the VM build agent and access the feed url, it works fine (no packages listed, but I thought this was normal).

I even tried formatting the VM and not messing with NuGet config; no luck.

So, I'm really stuck now. Any help welcome. I'm sure its something to do with proxy settings and Active Domain on Windows Server 2013, but that is all working as far as I can see.

Here is the log:

```
[09:57:06][Step 1/4] restore: Restoring NuGet packages for Data.sln (3s)
[09:57:06]NuGet command: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg\tools\NuGet.exe restore C:\BuildAgent\work\8eb62dff1e11de78\Data.sln -Source http://anwyn/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/ -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
[09:57:06]Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script2003394465901551489.cmd
[09:57:06]in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\8eb62dff1e11de78
[09:57:06]JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 8.0.30168.9
[09:57:06]Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-2.8
[09:57:06]Starting NuGet.exe 2.8.50506.491 from C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg\tools\NuGet.exe
[09:57:07]Installing 'AutoMapper 3.2.1'.
[09:57:07]Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 3.2.1'.
[09:57:07]Installing 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.668'.
[09:57:08]Successfully installed 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.668'.
[09:57:08]WARNING: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
[09:57:08]WARNING: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
[09:57:09]Installing 'NUnit 2.6.3'.
[09:57:09]Successfully installed 'NUnit 2.6.3'.
[09:57:09]Installing 'RhinoMocks 3.6.1'.
[09:57:09]Successfully installed 'RhinoMocks 3.6.1'.
[09:57:10]Unable to find version '0.1.3' of package 'RobGeoLtd.Core'.
[09:57:10]Unable to find version '0.1.22' of package 'RobGeoLtd.Measurement'.
[09:57:10]Process exited with code 1
[09:57:10][Step 1/4] Step Restore (NuGet Installer) failed
```

Update #1: Logged in as Domain account via Console:

[image: Console]

Going to ask our IT support to check the proxy/firewall to see what its doing... :/

Update #2: He was at a loss too; the Log:

```
[04/Sep/2014:11:57:46 +0100] "GET
http://anwyn/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc HTTP/1.0" 407 2167
TCP_DENIED:NONE 192.168.1.11 - local\devserver 

[04/Sep/2014:11:57:46 +0100] "GET
http://anwyn/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc HTTP/1.0" 503 2668
TCP_MISS:DEFAULT_PARENT
```

However, accessing the feed via IP rather than DNS name worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had our virtual machine (Agent) set up to have a bridged network connection. Prior to our server upgrade, this worked fine. After the upgrade, I had the above problem. I tried setting the VM connection to be NAT and that inexplicably fixed everything. Still think there is more going on here with the Proxy (I think its a Symantec Web Gateway proxy), AD and DNS alias as domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in linux administration so i have no clue how (and if its posibile) to set-up linux server into active directory domain. Can you please describe how did you configure Authentication section in your teamcity ? (login as administrator then under settings in Server Administrator => Authentication)

Can you access your teamcity feed via browser from this agents? Feed URI should be `http://SERVERNAME:PORT/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc` or if you're using public url (no authentication) `http://SERVERNAME:PORT/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc` ?

Comment: Auth is "Built-in", HTTP-basic. Yes, via the VM-agent (logged in as the domain account too) I can access the feed. Although, it doesn't show any packages; (i.e. I just see: the Collection element with `<atom:title>Packages</atom:title>`). TeamCity itself it running fine. Its the Windows 8 Build Agent that is acting odd. The same build works perfectly fine on my workstation.

Comment: If you're using built-in auth then you're not using AD auth, we're talking about guestApp feed right?

Comment: yeah, but the teamcity side of things was fine. I could access that on my own computer. The problem was/is something to do with the agent being a VM

Comment: can you access feed from a browser on agents vm?

Comment: In internet explorer - yes. via Nuget list -source `http://anwyn`... NO, via nuget list -source `http://192.168`... YES. It was a very odd problem. As soon as I changed to a NAT network type on the (agent) VM, it could access the teamcity feed via name too.

Comment: So you can access in IE with hostname, but from command line you can access only with IP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60670/discussion-between-dejan-dakic-and-meirion-hughes).